# Return object from AngularJS $scope ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I use the angularjs framework, I created an form.html and a controller.js with a variable that retrieves the SSID of a box. How to automatically assign the value of the variable in the form. This is an input field. When launching the application, the form should display the SSID automatically without the user needing to do so.

```
$scope.SSID {}; return [object Oject] in input form ng-model="SSID"
```

Thank you kindly help me.

**Controller.js**

```js
/*Controller*/

'use strict';

angular.module('djoro.controllers')
.controller('WifiSmartConfigCtrl', function($scope, $window, $ionicPlatform) {a
    $scope.SSID = {};

    $scope.getSSID = function() {
        var onSuccess = function(SSID) {
            $scope.SSID = SSID;
            return SSID;
        };
      
        var onFail = function() {};

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig.getSSID(onSuccess, onFail, $scope.SSID);
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content ng-controller="WifiSmartConfigCtrl">

        <form novalidate class="simple-form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>WI-FI</legend>
                <div class="list input-fields">
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <span class="input-label">SSID :</span>
                        <input type="text" name="test" ng-model="SSID" id="SSID" placeholder="SSID" required show-hide-input>
                    </label>
                    <label class="item item-input" show-hide-container>
                        <span class="input-label">Password :</span>
                        <input type="passwprd" name="test" placeholder="Password" required show-hide-input>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

Comment: looks like you have missed out adding the ng-app directive. you should do it like - <ion-pane ng-app='djoro.controllers'>.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function on the scope for getting the SSID but you never call is from the UI. If you want the UI automatically have it you need to call it in the controller initialization.

Your code for the controller will look like this:

```
.controller('WifiSmartConfigCtrl', function($scope, $window, $ionicPlatform) {a
    $scope.SSID = {};

    var onSuccess = function(SSID) {
        $scope.SSID = SSID;
        return SSID;
    };

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $window.cordova.plugins.Smartconfig
            .getSSID(onSuccess, angular.noop, $scope.SSID);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    I use a plugin cordova "smartConfig"

/*plugin.js*/

        function Plugin(){}

    Plugin.alert = function(content){
          var onSuccess = function(){};
          var onFail = function(){};
          cordova.exec(onSuccess, onFail, 'SmartconfigPlugin', 'alert', [content]);
    };


    Plugin.getSSID = function(onSuccess, onFail){
          cordova.exec(onSuccess, onFail, 'SmartconfigPlugin', 'getSSID', []);
    };

    module.exports = Plugin;
```

> SmartConfig.java

```
package fr.enersy.cordova.smartconfig;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import com.integrity_project.smartconfiglib.SmartConfig;
import com.integrity_project.smartconfiglib.SmartConfigListener;
import com.pandaos.smartconfig.utils.NetworkUtil;
//import fr.enersy.cordova.smartconfig.mySmartconfigListener;   // TODO remove from config.xml

public class SmartconfigPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

  // Variables declaration
  SmartConfigListener smartConfigListener;
  SmartConfig smartConfig;
  byte[] freeData;

  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    if("alert".equals(action)){
      final String content = args.getString(0);
      showAlert(content);
      callbackContext.success();
      return true;
    }

    else if("getSSID".equals(action)){
        String SSID = getSSID();
        callbackContext.success(SSID);
        return true;
      }

  }

  private String getSSID() {
      Log.i("--->> SmartconfigPlugin", "Enter getSSID");
      String SSID = (NetworkUtil.getWifiName(this.cordova.getActivity())).trim();   // TODO replace by something like: smartconfig_network_name_field.getText().toString().trim();
      Log.i("---------->> SmartconfigPlugin", "SSID: " + SSID);

      Log.i("---------->> SmartconfigPlugin", "Exit getSSID");
      return SSID;
  }

}
```